# Python: How to handle missing values in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I have a given CSV sample as follows:

```
ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,PRCP_AMT_J
90, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24109,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
150, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, DLY3208,900,1,30747,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-09 13:21,3,
174, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24775,1011,0.2,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,
```

I would like to determine the weekday of each given date in my CSV. My code which achieves that looks as follows:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt


csv_file = open('raindata.csv')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
field_names = list(csv_reader.fieldnames)
if 'WEEKDAY' in field_names:
    print "data has error"

elif 'RECWEEKDAY' in field_names:
    print "data has error"

else:
    field_names.insert(field_names.index('OB_DATE') + 1, 'WEEKDAY')
    field_names.insert(field_names.index('METO_STMP_TIME') + 1, 'RECWEEKDAY')

    def get_weekday(ob_date):
        return dt.strptime(ob_date, ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%A')

    output = open('raindata.csv','w')
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, field_names)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv_reader:
        row['WEEKDAY'] = get_weekday(row['OB_DATE'])
        row['RECWEEKDAY'] = get_weekday(row['METO_STMP_TIME'])
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

My script runs fine and gives the correct result but it fails where the `Date` values are missing from **OB_DATE** column and **METO_STMP_TIME** column.

How do I change the existing code, so that for a blank `Date` value the corresponding `Weekday` value is also blank?

Comment: @Rahul : ValueError: time data ' ' does not match format ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

Comment: @Rahul i know that it undertakes a string of the particular format but i want that for a blank it should give a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other alternative, you can modify your `get_weekday` function to handle a blank date.

```
def get_weekday(ob_date):
    return dt.strptime(ob_date, ' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime('%A') if ob_date.strip() else ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Just catch the exception that is thrown when the date/time string is missing or invalid and then set the value to an empty string.

```
try:
    row['WEEKDAY'] = get_weekday(row['OB_DATE'])
except ValueError:
    row['WEEKDAY'] = ''
```

Comment: could also use `if row["OB_DATE"]: ... else:...` instead of `try:... except:...` but it is really up to preference.

Comment: The output is nothing. the CSV was blank

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: The `try:...except:...` will also work for invalid dates (or wrongly formatted ones). So, it's probably a better solution than specifically checking for a falsy value.

Comment: @desmond.carros: You're opening the same file twice and read and write to that. That might wipe the file before it is even read. Use a different output and don't forget to close the files when you're done.

Comment: @jsfan but i am dealing with very big files. Initially i am working on samples of the file but when i will be trying this code on my final file then i cannot afford to compromise with the disk space.

Comment: that is the reason of opening and writing the same file.

Comment: @jsfan, if the date was malformed I would want the program to fail so like I said: it is really up to preference.

Comment: @desmond.carros: If you have enough memory, you can read the whole file into memory first and then write straight back to the file.

Comment: well i did what you said while i was commenting. i wrote the output to another file `raindata1.csv` and still the output is nothing. The CSV output is blank.

Comment: @desmond.carros: I ran your script (even without closing the files) and I got what I'm supposed to get.

Comment: @jsfan i am not sure why i am obsering this behaviour. well thanks much for the solution.